# Executing a jquery function to all href attributes

Tags: jquery

```
function openFile(file) {
    var extension = file.substr( (file.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
    switch(extension) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'png':
        case 'gif':
            alert('was jpg png gif');  
        break;                         
        case 'zip':
        case 'rar':
            alert('was zip rar');
        break;
        case 'pdf':
            alert('was pdf');
        break;
        default:
            alert('who knows');
    }
};

openFile("somestring.png");
```

I got this piece a code from another question posted here, but im unsure how to implement it for my purpose. I want to check the hrefs of every link and place the appropriate icon for the file type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.each` function:

```
$("a").each(function() { openFile($(this).attr('href')); }
```

It allows you to iterate through the matched sets of elements.

Comment: it must be me. I'm trying simple functions using the .each iteration and it won't work. Any ideas as to why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function () {
    openFile($(this).attr('href'));
});
```